# Remove all local folder mappings for a TFS workspace using command line

Tags: tfs

I can easily map/unmap working directories using tf.exe, but if a mapping to another folder, or the workspace root exists, this can still interfere with me mapping specific directories in a script.

Is there a way to remove all working directory mappings from a workspace so I know I've got a "clean slate" to work from?

Answer (score 0):

TF.exe doesn't support removing all folder mappings implicitly. However you can achieve that with PowerShell:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
                       "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
                       "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"


$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection")
$tfs.EnsureAuthenticated()
$vcs = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer])
$workspace = $vcs.GetWorkspace("workspace_name", "owner")

foreach($folder in $workspace.Folders)           
{   
       Write-Output "Removing $folder"
       $workspace.DeleteMapping($folder)
}
```